# NSInvocationOperation object release

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I've created `NSInvocationOperationQueue` object then added it into my `NSOperationQueue` instance.

```
operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];

NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(counterTask) object:nil];

[operationQueue addOperation:operation];

operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(colorRotatorTask) object:nil];
[operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

It works but I have questions. This [post](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-the-nsoperationqueue-class--mobile-14993) tells me that every operation should be release, but mine without release still works and it gives me error if I release it. If I do not release, is there any side effect or something will happen? Or is there any steps I missed that caused it cannot be released?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the project being created in the link you provided doesn't use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).

There's no reason not to be using ARC in any new project. With ARC you can avoid all of the attempts to call `release` or `autorelease` or `retain`. ARC will properly release the added operation when it is done.

The code you posted in your question is fine with regard to memory management as long as you are using ARC. And since you are getting errors trying to call `release` this means you are using ARC.

Comment: For now (xcode 7 and up), all of project which created is supporting ARC right? So I could ignore those memory management issue (`release`, `autorelease`, or `retain`) or should I pay attention on that?

Comment: ARC has been supported for the last several versions of Xcode. But yes, as I stated in my answer, you are using ARC so you can ignore (actually you have to ignore) any calls to `release`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, @rmaddy. You made my day!